# Error: java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: f != java.lang.String in orientdb

Tags: orientdb, graph-databases

I just started learning orientdb. I was trying to optimize database using command OPTIMIZE DATABASE -lwedges but is giving me error like this

```
Error: java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: f != java.lang.String
```

I know this error comes frequently in java but I don't know why it is there in orientdb? is anything wrong in my command? I checked [orient db manual here](https://orientdb.com/docs/2.2/SQL-Optimize-Database.html). it says it only supports lwedges right now then this command should run.I am using 2.2.22

Comment: Hi, it seems that f identifier expect a float when you are giving a String. This is a similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35279083/java-util-illegalformatconversionexception-f-java-lang-string-error

Comment: @MichelaBonizzi: I saw this post.but all are of some code.Here I didn't write code I am using jar provided by orient db.so what they have written I don't know